# Ext.NET 2.0 how to get the value of datefield

Tags: get, ext.net, datefield

I want to get from datefield. Ext.NET 2.0 is a little bit difficult to study. 
This is a source of simple datefield.

```
<ext:DateField ID="DateField1" runat="server" 
     Vtype="daterange" FieldLabel="To" EnableKeyEvents="true" />
```

and I'd like to set the value on my Textbox.

```
myTextbox.setValue(App.MainContent_DateField1.getValue());
```

help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the answer to this - using `getRawValue()` function

```
myTextbox.setValue(App.MainContent_DateField1.getRawValue());
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested the basic scenario and it appears to work correctly.

You might need to call `.format()` to convert your `DateField` value into a nicely formatted string, but that is not required.

Here's a full sample demonstrating the scenario. Select a `Date` from the `DateField`, then click the `Button`. The `DateField` value will be copied to the `TextField`.

**Example**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register assembly="Ext.Net" namespace="Ext.Net" tagprefix="ext" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />

        <ext:DateField ID="DateField1" runat="server" />
        <ext:TextField ID="TextField1" runat="server" />

        <ext:Button 
            runat="server" 
            Text="Submit" 
            OnClientClick="TextField1.setValue(DateField1.getValue().format('d-M-Y'));" 
            />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```